# Turning a localized Date to a Timestamp in Firebase

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore and since it doesn't seem like it has a native `createdAt/updatedAt` as part of a document, I'm creating them when I create the new document. Using a straight up `Date()` as the value for my initial dictionary that I save to Firestore obviously gives me a localized date/time – UTC -500, for example.

Firestore stores this as `November 19, 2018 at 5:14:54 PM UTC-5`

Is there a specific date format that Firestore likes in order to save something as a `Timestamp` and so that I will be able to sort on it later?

I tried using `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"` as the `dateFormat` from just printing out the value of `Date()` in a Playground. Would love some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp) object doesn't have a date format.  It's just a measurement of a number of [seconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#seconds) since Unix epoch, plus some number of [nanoseconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#nanoseconds).  It does not accept a formatted time.  If you have a formatted time, you will have to parse it to get a Timestamp object in return.`

The date format you're seeing in the console is just the way the console is choosing to format it.  If you want to format a Timestamp for display, you'll need to do that yourself.